# Using accepts_nested_attributes_for with single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model `Post` which `belongs_to` one `Section`. There are two different `Section` subclasses and I use STI to implement different behavior for each of them. In the `Post` form I would like to have a tab for each `Section`. The tab will let the user either A) Pick from an existing `Section` using a `<select>` or B) Let the user create a new `Section`. I would like to know how to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `fields_for` or whatever is required to get this done **The Rails Way**.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the tabs correspond to the two subclasses

```
class Post
  # the two subclasses. Each instance will only be using one or the other
  belongs_to :section_foo
  belongs_to :section_bar

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :section_foo
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :section_bar
end
```

And in the view (probably once per tab)

```
= form_for @post do |f|
  = f.select :section_id, SectionFoo.all # etc
  = fields_for @post.build_section_foo do |s|
    = s.text_field :bla_bla_bla
```

That should get you 85% of the way there. You might need some :reject_if bidness on the accepts_* to avoid creating a new section *and* assigning an old section.